# How hot does my laptop have to be for it to be damaging it?

Tags: laptop

I'm using the Acer Nitro 5 laptop, and whenever I start playing video games (mostly rocket league or gta), I average temperature of 90-94 degrees celcius and the fans get really loud (my laptop is pretty new as well).  Is it possible that I am damaging my laptop, and if so, what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Contact Acer support while the machine is in warranty and determine if the laptop should be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Most CPUs these days max out at about 100°. So long as they stay below that, your only issue is fan noise. Technically, they are designed to be able to run at those temperatures. Your lap will give up in the heat before your laptop will.

Laptops - whatever the manufacturers may like to tell/sell you - are not good at heat dissipation, hence are not good for gaming, or any high performance task.

Your only 'fix' is to use a laptop cooling pad to increase your airflow. Your 'real fix' is not to use a laptop for tasks better performed by a desktop.

Comment: There can be damage to adjacent components when components like CPU generate heat which can't be evacuated. most mechanical HDDs should always be at less than 55C, and while the 100C you cite is correct for the individual cores (T-Junction) the only component that will protect itself automatically is the CPU. If the Laptop is dirty, or the fans are going, heat can gradually build to levels that could be problematic, even if the CPU is not exceeding 100C.

Comment: Sure. That's covered in "laptops are not good at heat dissipation" & "get a desktop";) For some reason, people these days seem far too willing to sacrifice usability for portability.